# cannot navigate form login screen to bottom_tab_screen with provider

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to navigate from login screen to the bottom tab screen but nothing happen and now i have no error

it is the main

```
 return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: UserProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: AppProvider()),
      ],
      child:MaterialApp(
      key: key,
      title: 'Voyager',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme.getTheme(),
      routes: routes,
      ),
    );

  }
```

my dialog which has two cases if success or fail to login or sign up

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dialogs {
  static showErrorDialog(BuildContext context,
      {@required String message, @required int code}) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: Text('Ok'),
            )
          ],
          title: Text('error $code'),
          content: Text(message),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

my login method and it depend on user api provider

```
signIn() async {
    var res = await userProvider.login(
        _userNameController.text, _passwordController.text);

    if (res is FailedRequest) {
      Dialogs.showErrorDialog(widget._context , message: res.message, code: res.code);
      print('results ${res.toString()}');
    } else {
      print("Signing in success");

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          widget._context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomTabScreen()));
    }

    userProvider.isLoading = false;
  }
```

and the api provider which use in the login

```
Future<dynamic> login(String email, String password) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> body = {'email': email, 'password': password};

    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    print('Starting request');
    http.Response response = await http.post(Environment.userLogin,
        body: json.encode(body), headers: Environment.requestHeader);
    print('Completed request');
    print('user login response : ${response.body}');
    Map<String, dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
    var results;
    if (res['code'] == 200) {
      // login successful
      _user = User.fromJson(res['message']);
      results = true;
    } else {
      // login failed;
      results =
          FailedRequest(code: 400, message: res['error'], status: false);
    }
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return results;
  }
```

finally the failed request class if request not done

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class FailedRequest {
  String message;
  int code;
  bool status;

  FailedRequest({
    @required this.message,
    @required this.code,
    @required this.status,
  });
}
```

Comment: seems like the string you're returning is null .You mght want to try go null safe as follows `Text(message ?? "your message")`

Comment: @Ggriffo i try it the error is disappear but it still in the login screen it is not navigate

Answer (score 0):

The Issue seems to be with the res['error'] can you verify that the field error actually exists and is not null.

At this block can you print the value of res['error']

```
else {
  print(res['error']);
  // login failed;
  results =
      FailedRequest(code: 400, message: res['error'], status: false);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering and helping them. But your answer does not follow the guidelines of Stack Overflow. This should be in a comment section.

Comment: @AyushBherwani I do know that, I don't have enough reputation to make a comment, thus had to submit it as a answer

Comment: @PreetParekh i am not understand can you explain more ?

Comment: The problems on first glace seems to be the res['error'] that you're getting from the http package seems to be null, to isolate the problem can you try to either pass a string as  `results =
      FailedRequest(code: 400, message: "test", status: false);` OR just print the value of res['error'] and look into the console